# non-working Realtek Wireless Card on Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280

Tags: wireless, realtek, toshiba-satellite

Just bought a Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280. Immediately dropped Windows 8 for ArtistX. Apparently corrupted .iso, so I reinstalled with a new .iso (after they upgraded their build to 13.04, apparently) then just decided the whole thing was just too bloated so decided the smartest thing for someone that hasn't ever touched a terminal to do is go to the last LTS, 12.04. Throughout all of my ridiculous floundering there has been one constant since dropping Windows; no wireless support.

I am currently on the machine in question hooked directly to my router. No problems there. I've tried going on the Toshiba support website and downloading the drivers but there's no indication I'm not doing it wrong.

I've done some looking around online and learned to type lshw and, concerning the network, I get this:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
              description: Network controller
               product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
               vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
               version: 01
               width: 64 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: bus_master cap_list
               configuration: latency=0
               resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

and also, and it may be an unrelated issue, I have a serial saying it's unclaimed as well. It's a Hynex Semi-Conductor, apparently. I don't know what that is.

I'm seeing a lot of posts about the RTL8188 but they seem to be in Greek (or Unix, very little difference to me) so if someone could ELI5 (or like I'm a 30 year old man that has only just now walked away from Windows, anyway) I would appreciate it greatly. Kinda dove in head first and landed immediately over my head I guess.

Comment: Here is the process to install the driver for your device. It was tested and written for 13.04 but will probably but not necessarily work for 12.04 LTS. I suggest you try it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281

Comment: OK. Just tried it. After 'sudo make install' every other line is 'cannot read private key'. And after reboot it still doesn't work. What does that mean?

Comment: If you can spare $15, [this](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B003283M6Q/linuxp-20) is a good, Linux-compatible wifi card that you can plug into your USB port. I use it myself, and it works great.

Comment: thanks. if i can't get this thing beat with good old fashioned american bullheadedness, at least i know i have an out.

Comment: So, you've found the product code for your wireless card.
Now, for starters, check to see if the firmware is there for your card.
To do this launch the terminal and type: cd /lib/firmware ls -l

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Sep 29 19:44 rtlwifi -is this what i'm looking for?

Comment: 'cannot read private key' is harmless and may safely be ignored.Did you verify your device is 10ec:8179 as from the linked post?

Comment: Yes. Verified the 10ec:8179. Says (rev 01) after that. Don't know if that's significant. Then I followed those instructions to the letter. Still no go.

Comment: Are there any clues in the message files? dmesg | grep rtl

Comment: 2 things: terminal reacts in no way whatsoever when I type dmesg | grep rtl. Suddenly additional drivers recognizes my driver but says it is not currently in use. I have tried the wireless function key just in case it was just off but that too gets me nowhere. I'm also now getting 'KVM disabled in bios' on startup as well as a message about AMD microcode fam16.bin. Again, total noob, just dropping anything that looks out of the ordinary to me. Error messages at boot, in my limited experience, not desirable.

Comment: Is there maybe a way I can try turning on the card itself in the terminal? Not all of my F keys are responding properly so now that the driver is at least being recognized perhaps I can try another means of activation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link or follow the link above (Chili555) Followed the directions it works good it says for a Toshiba C55 A5281 and Ubuntu 13.04, I have a Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280, Ubuntu 12.04LTS all updates and 3.11.4 kernel,  [Wireless not working on Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281)

Answer (score 0):

You should give this driver a try:  https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

After having many issues with my RTL8188CE I finally downloaded the driver source code and fixed it myself.  It has been working beautifully for me ever since.  Make sure you download the one for your OS version.  For example, if you're on 12.04 then switch to the `ubuntu-12.04` branch.  The latest version on master is for 13.10 and the kernel headers have changed so the are NOT compatible.