# RTL8188EE doesn't detect any wireless signal

Tags: wireless

I am new to Linux, and I finally got 12.04 to dual boot with windows 8.  My problem is that I do not know how to get wireless card to connect.  It is not detecting any networks, and I have heard that getting Ubuntu to recognize the card is tough with windows 8.

It is a new laptop, and I do not know how to find the wireless card info.  I have tried to find additional drivers, but nothing proprietary is showing up.  Any help would be appreciated on where to go from here.

`lspci | grep Network` shows:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what it is showing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless not working on Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281)

Comment: @chili555, The solution you added got 12.04 to recognize the network, and I was connected for about 5 minutes.  It then lost connection, and now it acts like it is going to connect, but never does.  It will occasionally ask for a PW, which is typed in correctly, but still never connects.  What now?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is fixed with Ubuntu 13.10. (source: http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=15059781). (Sorry, my source is in French.

Before installing Ubuntu 13.10, you may try install a more recent version of the kernel.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid but I have no idea how to do that cochisebt.  I know I have a huge learning curve ahead of me, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get the information on this site. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/linux-kernel-3-12-released-install-ubuntu-or-linux-mint/. I suggest you to try this as the issue is fixed with Ubuntu 13.10, in order to avoid a new installation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee
sudo modprobe rtl8188ee swenc=1
```

If it helps, we can write a quick file and make it permanent.

I also suggest you experiment with wireless N turned off in the router. Does it connect and remain stable?

f you are still having trouble, let's try an even newer driver. I suggest you download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13-rc8/backports-3.13-rc8-1.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13-rc8-1/
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sudo modprobe rtl8188ee
```

Also, please be sure you installed the firmware as I said in the link.

Comment: OK, I did ran those lines and I am able to get on a public network with no PW, but still cannot connect to any networks with passwords.  It acts like its trying but continues to prompt for a password.