# Identify and Install Wireless Driver

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

I have just bought [this](http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/1467752.htm) and put Ubuntu on it. The wired internet connection works fine, but I have no option for wireless even though there is a built in wireless card. Can you help me dentify the card, and find an ubuntu driver for it?

Here is some detailed information [about](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=6705877#!tab=features).

- When I typed `lsusb` I got this

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
  Bus 003 Device 002: ID 064e:9301 Suyin Corp. 
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
  ```
- When I typed `iwconfig wlan1` I got:

  ```
  wlan1     No such device
  ```
- When I typed `lspci` I got:

  ```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
  00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
  00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
  00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
  00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8179 (rev 01)
  02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
  ```
- When I typed `iwconfig` I got:

  ```
  eth0      no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.
  ```
- When I typed `lshw -C network` I got:

  ```
  PCI (sysfs)  
    *-network UNCLAIMED     
         description: Network controller
         product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
         vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2500000-c2503fff
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
         vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: 07
         serial: a0:1d:48:d1:96:66
         size: 100Mbit/s
         capacity: 100Mbit/s
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
         resources: irq:41 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2404000-c2404fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff memory:afb00000-afb0ffff
  ```
- When I typed `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` I got:

Absolutely nothing (no errors).

What wireless card does my computer have? Where can I find a driver for ubuntu for it?

Comment: I solved this by following this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281/337855#337855