# Realtek 8188E not working after routine update

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, realtek

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A that has a Realtek 8188E wireless card. When I first installed Kubuntu to this machine, I had to start with 13.10 to get the card to work, but it continued to work when I upgraded to 14.04 after the initial install. Now, there was just a routine recommended update, and after rebooting, I can't get a wireless connection. I have searched extensively for a solution and tried the one [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281), but got errors when running make. I really do NOT want to have to start over with 13.10 every time there are routine system updates, so if anyone can help, I will be grateful.

The connection was working fine since I installed Kubuntu a couple weeks ago, and only went on the fritz after the update today.

I found this in the logs:

```
[   13.100650] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x40f79a2d for NID 0x1d
[   13.100651] realtek: Enabling init ASM_ID=0x9a2d CODEC_ID=10ec0269
[   53.887772] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2
[   55.019037] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 (try 1/3)
[   55.855573] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 (try 2/3)
[   56.868445] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 (try 3/3)
[   57.869344] wlan0: authentication with 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 timed out
```

numerous times followed by:

```
[ 6136.219868] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2
[ 6136.229893] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 (try 1/3)
[ 6136.231531] wlan0: authenticated
[ 6141.237997] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 6152.081403] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2
[ 6152.091258] wlan0: send auth to 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 (try 1/3)
[ 6152.092859] wlan0: authenticated
[ 6157.097625] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:f8:4a:a2:e2 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 6161.162629] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 6164.165572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

I have no idea what it means or how to fix it, though.

---

**Edit**: I have searched for 3 days for answers to getting this to work. I got a Netgear N150 USB WNA1000M adapter, and after following a youtube video for that installation, the best I can get is a few seconds of connection. It shows in connection manager as being connected, but I cannot even ping an outside source.

I tried blacklisting the drivers for the onboard Realtek adapter, and that made no difference with the Netgear USB.

It appears that there is something in 14.04 that keeps it from working properly with some wireless adapters, or at least on this Toshiba Laptop. If I could find out what USB adapter would work out of the box, I'd return the one I have and go that route.

Comment: You should look through the kernel log for relevant messages and post them here.  Run `dmesg | less` and see what you can find.  You might also start by running `dmesg | grep -i real | less`.  You also should be more specific: did the card work after the first time you rebooted after upgrading to 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

I know, this answer sounds lame, but consider buying a new (Intel) wireless card to replace yours. You can get one for 15-25$ on amazon and specifically look for its compatibility with Linux. 
Many non-Intel wireless cards tend to work unreliably on Linux...

A friend of mine had problems with his wireless on his notebook and that's how he solved the problem.