# Slow wifi connection in ubuntu 14.04 installed in HP pavilion

Tags: wireless, 14.04

My Ubuntu 14.04 OS WiFi connection is is very slow? My laptop is HP Pavalion, and I am dualbooting with Windows. What steps should I take to diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My Pavilion has a buggy driver.  The suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281) in #3 worked for me.

Good luck.