# Wifi will be amazing, and then it will go away

Tags: wireless

thanks for reading.

I recently asked a question about how to fix my wireless, and I thought I had fixed it until recently. My internet will move really fast, as it should be doing, and then it will return to the state where it won't allow me to go to any web pages. I have tried numerous fixes for Ubuntu 14.04, and I think I may need to make changes that are particular to my system.

Do I need to post the diagnostic data?

Here is my info:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView SSA-CUnit (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0c)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0c)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView SEC (rev 0c)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation ValleyView High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0c)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView PCI Express Root Port (rev 0c)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ValleyView Power Control Unit (rev 0c)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation ValleyView SMBus Controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)


Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b40d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 069: ID 05ac:12a0 Apple, Inc. iPhone 4S
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What wireless do you have? The commands lspci and lsusb should give some information if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try opening a Terminal window at startup and simply type

```
ping www.google.com
```

As for me, I received a message "ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available" after some time. This was due to an unsupported network card by the kernel. For me, it helped to install a new kernel.

... or you can try this solution for your RTL8188EE wifi card:
[Wireless not working on Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281)