# Wireless is extremely slow on my Toshiba Satellite C55-A5286 with RTL8188EE. Every other host on the same network gets great wireless speeds

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, toshiba-satellite

My laptop has Ubuntu 17.10 installed. Ever since I have had Ubuntu on this laptop (previously Windows 8 from manufacturer) the wireless speed has been terrible, to the point where I only max at about 500kbs while my peers on their windows and mac machines are getting 40mbps. It is absolutely frustrating as a student to have to wait years for any kind of content to load.

I have tried going down the rabbit hole of drivers but all i have really found is this post [Wireless not working on Toshiba Satellite C55-A5281](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337785/wireless-not-working-on-toshiba-satellite-c55-a5281) and it's pretty old in terms of Linux years. I am not an expert on linux drivers but I am pretty sure mine is up to date. here is the output of

```
lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

I don't have access to to the router since this is the schools network. I use my desktop at home. My laptop gets very low speeds anywhere but I mostly use it on campus.

Any guidance would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you for taking the time out of your busy schedules to read and respond to this post